# How do I run the Elmah script to create the db

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, elmah.mvc

I installed Elmah and now I get an error when I run my program. I see that the errors relate to the schema. So I realize I need to run a script to create the tables.

I have downloaded the script file. If I select run, a dialog box opens asking me to select a program to open the file. Dumb question what do I do select?

If I browse, I see both MS SQL Server and SQL Server Compact. If I select SQL Server I see folders 80, 90 etc.  Compact gives a folder V4.

Newbie- obviously, I have a big picture problem here, but I can't be the first. So some newbie help please.

I'm using MVC4/ef5  localdb\v11.  System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0 for my project DB.

JW

Answer (score 0):

**To run ELMAH on SQL Compact Edition**
SQL Compact Edition is a bit different than other editions. It is possible you have the ELMAH setup scripts intended for Express or Standard which are different.

To use ELMAH on Compact Edition, this blog post is a great starting point:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek7ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersWithSQLServerCompact.aspx

**To directly answer your question**
Generally you would run a .sql script with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. You can download the 2008 version from Microsoft.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593

the Microsoft Web Platform Installer may be an easier way to install the software on your development computer.

http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx